# HTTP header, Getting particular value

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

```
(string) HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 21:38:50 GMT
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie, Accept-Encoding
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 5000
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 4976
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

From the header above i want the value of **X-Ratelimit-Remaining**. How do i store that in a variable in php.

Comment: Looks like this covers it (check examples): http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: retagged with php curl and http-headers

Comment: The solution you accepted seems more complicated than the ones using `get_headers()`. Why is it preferable?

Comment: Please see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6 and http://php.net/http_parse_headers

Comment: where did you get this header from in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_headers()` ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)) to retrieve any value from the header.

Comment: `get_headers()` performs the GET request from the URL and returns the response-headers, it doesn't operate on a string.

Comment: It returns an array.  You can then grab the info from the array.  Plus, @Znarkus doesn't specify that he already has the information.

Comment: Didn't know about `get_headers()`. Actually seems like a better solution than mine, if I'm not missing something

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution using Curl:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/'); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true, 
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
)); 

$headers = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/^X-Ratelimit-Remaining: (.+)$/m', $headers, $m);
list(, $remaining) = $m;

echo '$remaining: ' . $remaining;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first answer from **@justderb** already said, use **get_headers()** PHP function.

If you have a string with the header info. you can convert into an array an get it anyway.

Example:

```
$url = "http://www.your-web.com";
$xr = get_headers($url, 1);
echo 'The X-Ratelimit-Remaining value is: '.$xr['X-Ratelimit-Remaining'];
```

Or:

```
$url = Array(
    "0" => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
    "Date" => "Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:14 GMT",
    "Server" => "Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)",
    "X-Ratelimit-Remaining" => "4976"
);
echo 'The X-Ratelimit-Remaining value is: '.$url['X-Ratelimit-Remaining'];
```

Hope it helps,

good luck!